# D3.js creates duplicates of similar datasets

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I'm using React to visualize large datasets, and I send the datasets to the React class as JSON:

How do I make D3 only redraw what has changed (one dataset)? I can draw the static curves as static elements, but I would like D3 to handle this for me for more flexibility in my code.

Note: I tried using the  `key`  in the `.data(dataset, key)` section, but that didn't respond to changes in the dataset.

Code:

```
var el = this.getDOMNode(); // for React
var SVG = d3.select(el).append("svg");
SVG.append('g')
 .attr('class', 'newSelection');

var g = d3.select(el).selectAll('.newSelection')
var line = d3.svg.line() // send arrays with [y,x] to this function to create lines
    .x(function(d){
        return scales.x(d[1])
    })
    .y(function(d){
        return scales.y(d[0])
    })
    .interpolate("basis");

var graphdata = this.props.graphdata; //to get data from React class

var lines = g.selectAll('.newSelection')
        .data(graphdata); 
    //enter
lines.enter()
    .append('g') // for me to recognize the paths
    .attr('class', function(d){
        return ('path '+d.Title)
    })
    .append('path')
    .attr('id', function(d){
        return d.Title
    })
    .attr('d', function(d){
        return line(d.data)})
    .attr('stroke-width',2)
    .attr('stroke','blue')
    .attr('fill', 'none');
// exit
lines.exit().remove();
```

Yes, I'm relatively new to D3.

Comment: Show us your code and some data, please. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/).

Comment: Added my code example now

Comment: I found the problem, I didn't define the class name <code>newSelection</code> in the lines.enter() section, so no new objects were found on each iteration.